# Schema specified is not valid

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

Ive been getting an error, I have an error with the entity framework. I have a SQL Server 2005 SP2.

When the ProviderManifestToken =  "2008" I get this error.

```
The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'.
```

Ive done the change [shown here](http://weblogs.asp.net/kencox/archive/2010/11/15/fix-the-version-of-sql-server-in-use-does-not-support-datatype-datetime2.aspx) and when chagned to "2005" I get

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
DatabaseAccess.Schema.Model1.ssdl(2,123) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must
target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different 
from '2005' that was encountered earlier.
```

I dont understand

My Database version is Microsoft SQL Server Standard Edition (64-bit) 9.00.3042.00

Ive tried deleting the schema and re adding it to no avail. Restarting etc

Ive alse made all my date time fields nullable

Comment: `datetime2` data type is not available in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I know, i dont how it is picking it up, in my config the   public Nullable<global::System.DateTime> MessageDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _MessageDate;
            }
            set
            {
                OnMessageDateChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("MessageDate");
                _MessageDate = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("MessageDate");
                OnMessageDateChanged();
            }
        }

Comment: cant also find datetime2 in any of my source code

Comment: `datetime2` is a SQL data type, not a .NET data type. Each of your entities' properties maps from a .NET type to a SQL type based on which provider you're using (SQL Server 2005, 2008, etc).

Comment: ok that is understood great, how do I get around the issue  ?

Comment: Open up `Model1.ssdl` and change the ProviderManifestToken from "2008" to "2005".

Comment: I get the error Schema specified is not valid. Errors: 
DatabaseAccess.Schema.Model1.ssdl(2,123) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must
target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different 
from '2005' that was encountered earlier.

Comment: <Schema Namespace="Capeled.BusinessLogic.DatabaseAccess.Schema.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" ProviderManifestToken="2005" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">

Comment: Then perhaps check all of your models to make sure that they all have the same value for ProviderManifestToken?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7763/discussion-between-welsh-king-and-brian-driscoll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this before and it is to do with the datetime being Nullable.  I think if you break into the code you will see that the value of the date time when you create a new instance of the class is a default(DateTime) and not null and it is this value that is causing the error.

If possible, can you try nulling the DateTime value before saving changes on the context?

I will try to put together a sample demonstrating when and how this occurs.

Found a brief explanation here:

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/bmains/archive/2010/11/19/entity-framework-4-and-quot-the-conversion-of-a-datetime2-data-type-to-a-datetime-data-type-resulted-in-an-out-of-range-value-quot.aspx

Comment: I nulled all the fields as suggested and set the Database to 2005 it breaks with : DatabaseAccess.Schema.Model1.ssdl(2,123) : error 0169: All SSDL artifacts must target the same provider. The ProviderManifestToken '2008' is different from '2005. I set it to 2008 and it breaks with The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'datetime2'.

Comment: I managed to fix this by destroying the whole business logic project and basically re writing all the database BLL it then worked. Must of been a gremlin somewhere